# I need to add disabled property to only those checkboxes whose values is equal to the value returned from my mongoDatabase using ejs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I need to add disabled property to only those checkboxes whose values is equal to the value returned from my mongoDatabase using ejs. Please help me implement it.

This is my ejs page:

````
             ```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="LayoutMain">
  <div class="Head">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
<form name="qwer" action="/" method="post">

<% for(let i=0; i<lool.length;i++){ %>

 <%= lool[i].seat %>

 <script>

 var a = $('.seat input:checkbox').val();
 if(a == (<%= lool[i].seat %>)){
  $('.seat input:checkbox').prop("disabled",true);
 }
 </script>

<% } %>

<ol class="block1">
    <li class="row row--1">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">

            <li class="seat">
            <input type="checkbox" name="go" value=100 id="1A" />
             <label for="1A">1A</label>
           </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="go" value=101  id="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="go" value=102 id="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="go" value=103  id="1D" />
          <label for="1D">1D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="go" value=104 id="1E" />
          <label for="1E">1E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="go" value=105 id="1F" />
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--2">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="go" value=106 id="2A" />
          <label for="2A">2A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="go"  value=107 id="2B" />
          <label for="2B">2B</label>
        </li>

            ```
````

This is a part of code, there are lots more checkboxes. I am not sure how to compare each and every checkboxes value.

Comment: `$('.seat input:checkbox')` includes all matching elements but `$('.seat input:checkbox').val()` will always return value of only the first one. Really not clear what the matching rules are here. Provide some sample data and appropriate html in order to create a [mcve]

Comment: updated. Thanks a lot for looking into it.

Comment: Still not clear what the values need to be compared to. You will need to provide more specific details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.... (And put this at the bottom of your page)

```
<script>

   var lools = [];

<% for(let i=0; i<lool.length;i++){ %>    
   lools.push('<%= lool[i].seat %>');     
                 //I AM ASSUMING lool[i].seat RETURNS THE VALUE @i IN lool ARRAY
<% } %>

$.each('.seat input:checkbox', function(){
   if($.inArray($(this).val(), lools) >= 0){
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
   }
})

</script>
```